# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const temp1' to 'temp2'

Tags: c++, templates

Could anyone let me know the reason why compiler doesn't like my below code?

I use VS2010. I cannot use C++ 11 or above. I have a template function definition in a header file and I invoke that function from another cpp file.

> header.h

```
typedef struct temp1
{
  int x;
  double d;
}
temp1;

typedef struct temp2
{
  double d;
  int x;
}
temp2;

class A
{
  public:
    A();
    ~A();

  public:   
    template<typename T1> void foo(const T1& xx, int x)
    {
      if( 1 == x )
      {         
        temp1 t1 = xx;
        //  Do some operation
      }

      if (2 == x )
      {
        temp2 t2 = xx;
        // Do some operation        
      }
    }                                      
  };
```

> Source.cpp

```
  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
    A temp;

    temp1 t1;
    t1.x = 10;
    t1.d = 10.10;   

    temp2 t2;
    t2.x = 20;
    t2.d = 20.20;

    temp.foo(t1,1);
    temp.foo(t2,2);

    return 0;
  }
```

Error reported by Compiler:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const temp1' to 'temp2'
Error   2   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const temp2' to 'temp1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Templates are a pure *compile-time* construct. That means *all* of the code has to be correct when you build it.

Since you want to do run-time selection depending on arguments passed it will not work.

The simple solution is to have two overloads of the function instead of a single template function: One function which takes `temp1` as argument, and the other which takes `temp2`.

---

On an unrelated note, you don't need `typedef` for structures in C++. The structure name is a type-name just like classes. Classes and structures are almost the same in C++, the only difference being the default visibility (`public` for structures and `private` for classes).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has te generate valid code for your template functions for all possible parameter values. So when you do the call `temp.foo(t1,1);` it creates an instance for the template function in which it has te be able to assign t1 to temp2 which it can't. That the if in which that happens is not executed because x == 1 is not relevant to the compiler because it generates an instance that can also be called with other values for `x`.